# Adding a webpart to existing spfx solution via yeoman generates error

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling

When I run the following commands to create a sharepoint framework solution, change directory to the new solution and then add a second web part to the solution...

`yo @microsoft/sharepoint --solutionName "intranet" --framework "react" --componentType "webpart" --componentName "myteam" --componentDescription "My Team Members" --environment "onprem" skipFeatureDeployment true
cd intranet
yo @microsoft/sharepoint --componentType "webpart" --componentName "test1" --framework "react" --componentDescription "test1234" --skip-install`

...the result is an error "cannot read property 'foreach' of undefined":

[image: cannot read property foreach of undefined]

My Yeoman package version is 1.3.2:

    `{
  "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": {
    "version": "1.3.2",
    ...`

I get the same result regardless of generating a react or knockout project.  Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like a bug in the SharePoint Framework. I've submitted an issue at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/921 where it will be picked up by the SPFx engineering team.